# Javascript age function

Tags: javascript, function

```
function checkAge() {
    var age = prompt("Enter your age");
    if (age >= 16) {
        console.log("Eligible for play")
    } else if (age <= 15) {
        console.log("Not old enough, please close this window")
    } else {
        confirm("Please enter in a number") checkAge();
    }
};
```

I don't know what's wrong and it's stressing me out the console returns unexpected identifier. What I want to happen is if you're 16 and up, it writes you can play, if you're lower than that, you can't, and anything else reruns the question. Thanks very much, I'm sort of new to this.

Comment: `confirm("Please enter in a number") checkAge();` right there

Comment: note you are comparing string to number. Use proper `;` and your current problem dissapears

Comment: @charlietfl That's actually ok, but it is definitely recommended to parse it into a number before doing comparisons :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yeah...I know it's not required but good habits help

Comment: @Manatee Shirt Doing something like `+age > 16` is good enough for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error due to:

```
confirm("Please enter in a number") checkAge();
```

Here is an example if you want to create the loop correctly:

```
function checkAge () {
    var age = prompt("Enter your age");
    if (age) {          
        if (age >= 16) {
        console.log("Eligible for play")     
        }
        else if (age <= 15) {
        console.log("Not old enough, please close this window")
        }
    }
    else {
        var r = confirm("Please enter in a number");
        if (r == true) {
            return checkAge()
        }
    }
};

checkAge();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
confirm("Please enter in a number");        
checkAge();
}
```

I got it to work guys thank you guys so much it was just that one semicolon that I left out that messed it all up. I didn't know you could run two things in one else statement lol but I'm glad it works now. I kinda understand how parseing works but I couldn't see how to apply it to this, anyways thank you guys